# confusion_matrix error 'list' object has no attribute 'argmax'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

I am working on a classification report for DCNN model, But I am facing an error. My code is

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

test = ImageDataGenerator()
test_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_data = test_generator.flow_from_directory(directory="/content/dataset/test",target_size=IMAGE_SHAPE , color_mode="rgb" , class_mode='categorical' , batch_size=1 , shuffle = False )
test_data.reset()

predicted_class_indices=np.argmax(pred,axis=1)
cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels, predictions.argmax(axis=1))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'argmax'
```

Comment: Although the diagnosis here was easy, in the future please post the full error trace. Notice also that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Comment: from where do the `pred`, `predictions` come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `predictions` is obviously a Python list, and lists do not have an `argmax` attribute; you need to use the Numpy function `argmax()`:

```
predictions = [[0.1, 0.9], [0.8, 0.2]] # dummy data
y_pred_binary = predictions.argmax(axis=1)
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'argmax'

# Use Numpy:
import numpy as np
y_pred_binary = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
y_pred_binary
# array([1, 0])
```

Comment: Thank You. However, y_pred_binary = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

I am facing another error that is 

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1 @desertnaut

Comment: @TurjoyAhmed this happens only if your `predictions` consists of a *single* tuple, i.e. `predictions=[p0, p1]` (where indeed there is no axis 1); but in such a case a confusion matrix is meaningless. Please **update** your post to show exactly what the `predictions` variable is. And what is `preds` in the previous line? The command there should return what you are actually looking for (assuming that `preds` is indeed your predictions), and *not* the indices as you seem to think.

Comment: @TurjoyAhmed accept the answer if it solves your problem.